# How to detect PTT button holding on Bluetooth PTT microphone iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth PTT mic 
[(Delking PTT Bluetooth Mic)](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/60132431061/Android_cell_phone_Bluetooth_ptt_microphone_for.jpg)

Now I want to use it in my small PTT app in iOS, and my problem is I don't know how to detect the PTT button is hold/release, I could see Zello app works great.

Can you all have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Headset remote control API to control this bluetooth microphone

```
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {
    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
        switch(receivedEvent.subtype) {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                //Insert code

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                //Insert code for HOLDING BUTTON
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                // Insert code for RELEASE BUTTON
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
                //Insert code.
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Muc Dong, I did try this solution but it seems remoteControlReceivedWithEvent method never be called

Comment: You should play an audio file to make remote controller's event work. Maybe play a silent mp3 file for exam.